# Script to Run Audacity On a Schedule

Tags: 13.10, audacity

After reading the doc and wiki for Audacity, I see there is a timer recording feature, which is exactly what I need, however, I do not see an option for recurring record sessions. Is there a way to have Audacity record for a set time, say 24 hours, export the audio, and start over with another 24 hour recording? I need this cycle to be perpetual. I apologize if this has been covered somewhere before, but I was unable to locate any information on this.